# How to do for..where functionally in Swift?

Tags: swift, functional-programming

I have an array called filters with true and false in it indicating whether to certain index positions in data array should be processed.

How would I do the following using functional approach (map/filter/reduce)?

```
var targetData: [String] = []
for i in 0..<filters.count where filters[i] {
    targetData.append(data[i])
}
```

Comment: This is probably clearer as is unless you transform (or model it like that in the first place) the data to something more amenable to `filter`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many possibilities, for example:

```
let filteredData = zip(filters, data)
   .filter { (shouldKeep, _) in shouldKeep }
   .map { (_, item) in item }
```

or

```
let filteredData = zip(filters, data)
   .filter { $0.0 }
   .map { $0.1 }
```

Note that the easiest way to handle two connected arrays is to merge them into one array.

Comment: I would give it a better name, like `shouldKeep` (a noun, or noun phrase) rather than `add` (which is a verb). You can also omit the parenthesis in the closures

Comment: Note that you can always combine `map` and `filter` to `flatMap`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` on `data.enumerated()`, then `map` to get back the filtered elements without the offsets.

```
let originalData = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
let filters = [true, false, false, true]
let filteredData = originalData
                       .enumerated()
                       .filter{ offset, _ in filters[offset] }
                       .map{ $0.element }
print(filteredData) // ["a","d"]
```

Or using `zip`:

```
let newFilteredData = zip(originalData, filters).filter({ data, keepIt in keepIt}).map{$0.0}
```

Comment: zip would be a better approach